# Show that $(C,\rho)$ is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $C$ is the class of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Define the metric on $C$ to be $\rho(f,g)=\sup\{|f(t)-g(t)|\}$, for $f,g\in C$. We need to prove that $(C,\rho)$ is a separable metric space.

I know that the class of [Bernstein polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) is a countable dense set of $(C,\rho)$ and that meets my needs, however I am looking for a more simple elegant proof of separability. Any hints?

Comment: since $[0,1]$ is compact, it is equivalent and less confusing if you write $\rho(f,g)=\max_{[0,1]} |f-g|$ instead of using "$\sup$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is simple but not so elegant. Let $N, M, K \in \mathbb N$. Consider

$$L_{N, M,K} = \{ P: [0,1] \to \mathbb R: P\ \text{is piecewise linear}, P(i/M) = j/K\},$$

where $i=0, 1, \cdots M$ and $j = -NK, -NK+1, \cdots ,NK$. $L_{N, M, K}$ is finite and

$$L = \bigcup_{N, M, K} L_{N, M, K} \subset C$$

is countable.

Let $f\in C$. Then $||f||\leq N$ for some $N\in \mathbb N$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there is $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Let $M$ be chosen such that $2/M < \delta$. Let $K$ be chosen such that $2/KN < \epsilon/2$. Let $P\in L_{N, M, K}$ such that $|f(i/M) - P(i/M)|<1/K$ for all $i$.

Let $x\in [0,1]$. Then there is $i$ such that $i/M \leq x<(i+1)/M$. Let $1>\lambda \geq 0$ such that

$$ x = \lambda \frac{i}{M} + (1-\lambda)\frac{i+1}{M}\ .$$

Using $P(x) = \lambda P(i/M) + (1-\lambda)P((i+1)/M)$,

$$|f(x) - P(x)|\leq \lambda |f(x) - P(i/M)| + (1-\lambda) \big|f(x) - P((i+1)/M) \big|$$

Using 
$$|f(x) - P(i/M)| \leq |f(x) - f(i/M)| + |f(i/M) - P(i/M)|<\epsilon/2 + 1/K< \epsilon$$

and similar for $P((i+1)/M)$, we have

$$|f(x) - P(x)| <\epsilon$$

Thus $L$ is dense in $C$.